# Is it safe/possible to hold user accounts on an ntfs partition?

Tags: hardware, users, ntfs

I know I can link folders in **/home/fancyusername** to a folder on an NTFS partition, but would it be safe to store an entire **/home/blabla** in this same manner?

Would the system choke up on permissions?
I'm asking because our system got damaged in a hurricane (fried) and the only bootable drive (so far) is a 3GB drive! I've got maverick on it, but need to get space for other users, espc my father, so we can get our Church information flowing etc.

This very critical so I can't take major risks.
Any information would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTFS is a POSIX-compatible filesystem, so it is possible with some work (related to permissions & user management).

OTOH, I don't think this is used very much, so it's not well-tested either...

Comment: thanks +)! As it's not tested (be me either) I'll avoid it for now. will accept once the timer expires.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend sticking to an ext3 or ext4 drive and then using symlinks for ~/Pictures ~/Videos etc to directories on a mounted-elsewhere NTFS drive (which would make your Places menu still work)

Comment: I was thinking of doing it that way, but hoping to avoid the extra work :( (time considered). guess I have little choice. thanks Maco